# Удаление самоответов с объяснением о несостоятельности вопроса

Tags: обсуждение, очередь-проверок, модерация, удаление-ответов, самоответы

Обходил очередь сообщений низкого качества и заметил, что иногда проверяющие голосуют за удаление ответов от человека, задавшего вопрос, где он объясняет, что задача больше не воспроизводится (или что нашёл опечатку).

[Пример 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/162264)
[Пример 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/162789)

Я считаю, что это может навредить судьбе вопроса (который, насколько я понимаю, в итоге нужно просто удалить как бесполезный).

Дело в том, что ответ можно удалить после закрытия вопроса. Без этого ответа кто-то может подумать, что вопрос был ошибочно закрыт и переоткрыть его (или каким-то другим способом усложнить удаление *вопроса*).

Предлагаю обсудить, как поступать с подобными ответами. Стоит ли их удалять или, наоборот, оставлять?

Comment: Закрытый вопрос без ответа система удалит гораздо быстрее, чем вопрос с заплюсованным "Блин сам по тупости пропустил закрывающий тег , блин пол дня убил."

Comment: @PashaPash с заплюсованным ответом вроде как вообще не удалит.

Comment: Да можно вообще ничего не удалять, кроме спама.

Comment: По моему надо удалять все вопросы низкого качества,и заплюсованные и нeт.Aто собирается много мусора.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan понятие качества - это относительное понятие. Например, один участник может воспринимать вас как гуру, тогда как другой участник может считать вас начинающим программистом. То же самое и с качеством вопроса.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Существует объективный подход.Если несколько человек говорят и приносят доведи что это не качественно то по моему стоит обращать на это внимание.

Comment: @VanyaAvchyan Можно обращать на это внимание, но тем не менее это не является объективным.

Answer (score 5):

Резюмирую сказанное в комментариях. Подобное сообщение следует удалять, вопрос
закрывать. Причины:

- ТС может отметить такой ответ зелёной галочкой, и [Дух сообщества](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/u/-1)
  никогда не удалит вопрос с подобным ответом.
- Ответ может получить положительный рейтинг, и такой ответ (и вопрос)
  система сама не удалит.

Чтобы ускорить удаление темы, нужно открыть её страницу и проголосовать за
закрытие вопроса как не соответствующего тематике.

Answer (score 0):

В свою очередь, предлагаю добавить кнопку(или какой-то пункт в "тревога", например) с названием "Ошибка в исходном вопросе" или кнопку "Вопрос задан по ошибке". Последний вариант мне нравится больше. Можно проголосовать за него, и ТС может его сам поставить. И это будет логично, по-моему.

Comment: Уже есть. "Не по теме" > "Вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой"

Comment: Спасибо,  ну тогда у меня все